# JQuery select the third column of a table and add a span in this td with a special class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, datatables

I am using play 1.2.5 and create my table with this code

```
    <div class="pdx_std_north_panel">
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <th>Property</th>
        <th>Value</th>      
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <button id="create-property">Create new property</button>
        #{list items:paras, as:'elem' }
        <tr >
            <td>${elem.sendAllKey}</td>
            <td id="${elem.sendAllKey}" >${elem.sendAllValue}</td>      
            <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" id="deleteRow" name="${elem.sendAllKey}"></span></td>                       
        </tr>       
        #{/list}
    </tbody>    
    </table>        

</div>
```

To add a row I am adding it by using the function fnAddData of the Datatables jquery plugin. This works, but the third column of my new row is empty. I need to add into this cell a span with a special class. Otherwise my delete button is not visible.

I guess that i can do that by using jquery and adding a span somehow. Can somebody show me how to select the third column of my new added row?

Also if i selected this cell, how can i add a span with the given class?

thanks

Answer (score 8):

This is how to select:

```
$("#table_id td:eq(2)")
```

An this is how to add:

```
var tableData=$("#table_id td:eq(2)"),
span=$('<span class="specialClass">some text</span>');
tableData.append(span);
```

For your comment question here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/umXWW/

Html code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>abcd1</td>
    <td>abcd2</td>
    <td>abcd3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
    <td>bbbb</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('td:contains("aaaa")').css({border:'1px solid red'}).parent().find('td:eq(2)').append($('<span class="specialClass">some text</span>'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can i achieve to retrieve the third cell of the row if I only know that the first column cell has the value aaaa                                       <table id="table_id" class="display dataTable" aria-describedby="table_id_info"> <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <tr class="odd">
    <td class=" sorting_1">aaaa</td>
    <td id="aaaa" class=" ">edrfg</td>
<td class=" ">
</tr> ...